# Update/Put Route - Method not allowed

Tags: php, slim

I'm using postman to test my API, but right now I have a problem with the put routes.
So this is a put route I wrote:

```
$app->put('/setting/{id}/settingvalue', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, Response

Interface $response, $args) {

    try {
        $user = new \Riecken\PBS\controller\SettingsValueController();
        $result = $user->updateOneSettingsValueinDetail( $args['id'], $request->getParsedBody());
        $response = $response->withJson($result);
        $response = $response->withStatus(200);
        return $response;

    }catch(Exception $e) {

        $response->getBody()->write($e->getMessage());
        return $response->withStatus($e->getCode());

    }

});
```

And this is the function which you see above (updateOneSettingsValueinDetail):

```
public function updateOneSettingsValueinDetail ($settingsvalueIdToUpdate, $body) {

    try {

        return $this->SettingsValueDao->update($settingsvalueIdToUpdate, $body);

    }catch(DAOException $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->returnErrorMessage(), $e->returnHttpCode());
    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception("System Error", 500);
    }


}
```

The problem is that Postman tells me that the Method is not allowed, only POST and GET is allowed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAMNj.png)

Does anybody know what type of problem that is and what the solution could be?

Comment: If you use apache: any error messages in the apache error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This response is come from Slim's NotAllowedHandler. And it is not only POST and GET as default. This response is not related to your mentioned above code.

Are you sure you don't customize "NotAllowedHandler" and you don't bind to app as middleware?

I wrote this code that containing that would create the same situation:

```html
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Slim\App;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App([]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $allowed = ['GET', 'POST'];
    if (!in_array($request->getMethod(), $allowed)) {
        $notAllowed = new \Slim\Handlers\NotAllowed();
        return $notAllowed($request, $response, $allowed);
    }
    $next($request, $response);
});

$app->put('/setting/{id}/settingvalue', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {
    die("Expected Context via PUT");
});

$app->get('/setting/{id}/settingvalue', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {
    die("Expected Other Context via GET");
});

$app->run();
```

I hope to it help you.